# How can I send and error when I get an input that is not a number? [C#]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, syntax-error, console-application

I want an error to appear when the client writes a symbol or a letter

```
int n = 0;
string ent;

ent = Console.ReadLine();
n = int.Parse(ent);

if (n.GetType() != typeof(int)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Must be a number");
}
```

Comment: In C# your n won't change its type unless you make it dynamic. So the type check will always evaluate to true.
You can try to use int.TryParse() which returns Boolean where 'false' means it couldn't parse the input probably due to non numeric input.

Comment: Sounds like you could use int.TryParse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the official docs and the example usage:

Either wrap the `int.Parse` in a try-catch block as suggested in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-7.0#system-int32-parse(system-string)) or use `int.TryParse()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-int32-tryparse(system-string-system-int32@)).

Try catch example:

```cs
int n = 0;
string ent;

ent = Console.ReadLine();
try {
    n = int.Parse(ent);
} catch (FormatException) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Must be a number", ent);
}
```

Comment: of both your options to show an example-code you should definitly chose the second one which does not rely on handling exceptions for program-flow.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I wanted to encourage them to read the official docs as there are always some examples. Also, try-catch may be a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Yes. Even though the TryCatch works, this situation a very good example of when to use TryParse instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do but this would prompt on any input if it was able to parse the input:

```
while ( true )
{
    bool isValid = int.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out int parsedInput );

    if ( !isValid )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Must be a number" );

        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine( $"Your input was: {parsedInput}" );
}
```

Please note, that this code is for demonstration purposes, using `while` loops as shown can, and will result in unexpected behavior's.

Comment: You have an infinite loop here, it seems you want `break` after `Console.WriteLine( $"Your input was: {parsedInput}" );`

Comment: Yeah, the infinite loop here is intentional. Good starting point to play around. I don't know what OP is building, they might not need exiting the loop. Maybe they don't even need such a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be a to use int.TryParse. As the name suggests, it tries to convert the given value to int and returns a boolean value of true or false indicating if it succeeded.
It also receives an out parameter where the final parsed value will be stored if the conversion goes well.
It would look something like this:

```
int n = 0;
string ent;
bool validNumber = false;

while(!validNumber){
    ent = Console.ReadLine();
    if(int.TryParse(ent, out n))
    {
        validNumber = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Must be a number");
    }
}
```

I also added a while loop to keep asking for a valid number.